# have to find cartesian-coordinates from the given diagram

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Honestly, I don't know where to start in this question

> The cartesian co-ordinates of the point $Q$ in the figure is :
> **(a)** $(\sqrt{3}, 1)$
> **(b)** $(-\sqrt{3}, 1)$
> **(c)** $(-\sqrt{3},-1)$
> **(d)** $(\sqrt{3},-1)$

Comment: Where to start?  A good place to start would be in understanding what the $\sin$ and $\cos$ functions are and what the [unit circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_circle) is.  From there, note that this is not exactly the unit circle since the radius is larger, but the results can be adjusted to match.  It is expected that you memorize the common values in the unit circle corresponding to angles which are integer multiples of $30^\circ$ and $45^\circ$ or equivalently $\frac{\pi}{6}$ and $\frac{\pi}{4}$ respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, by the Theorem of angles opposed by the vertex, the angles opposite each other when two lines cross are always equal.

Here, I will denote the intersection between the circumference and the $Ox$ axis, the point which is part of the arc ${RQ}$ as $M$. By the theorem which I stated we then get that $\angle MOQ  = -\pi/6$ radians $ = 30 \deg$.
We will now use the sine and cosine function to find $MQ$ and $OM$, respectively.
$$\sin {\angle MOQ} = \frac{MQ}{OQ} \Rightarrow MQ =1 $$
$$\cos {\angle MOQ} = \frac{OM}{OQ} \Rightarrow OM = \sqrt3 $$
Now, notice that $OM = pr_{Ox}{OQ}$ so $-OM=x_Q$ (that is obvious from the drawing) and $QM=pr_{Oy}OQ$ so $MQ=y_Q$.
Thus we get that $Q=(-\sqrt3, 1)$.